# How can I change the boot sequence in Ubuntu 23.10?

Tags: boot, suspend, wayland, 23.10, app-center

I want to change the boot sequence in Ubuntu 23.10.

I have Windows 11 and Ubuntu 23.10 on my laptop, and Ubuntu is not working well.

Comment: #1, #2, and #3 look like bugs. Your role is to [report bugs properly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug), to assist developers in duplicating the bugs in their test environment, and to help text the fixes to ensure that they really do work. #4 looks like an upstream issue that you, again, need to report to them (not to us). None of those seem related to changing the boot sequence. Avoid complaining -- we are not the Ubuntu developers. We are your peer users.

Comment: The Ubuntu boot sequence uses systemd targets. Do a bit of research on those. Once you understand them and how they work, you can rearrange the boot sequence almost any way you wish.

Comment: Also, editing the /etc/default/grub, adding lines GRUB_DEFAULT=saved  

GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true  

will set grub to boot the last OS selected for boot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I change the GRUB boot order?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order)

Answer (score 1):

This answer will solve some of your problems:

- [Is there a way for grub to automatically reboot into Windows from Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1014467/is-there-a-way-for-grub-to-automatically-reboot-into-windows-from-windows/1014491#1014491)
- When you reboot from Windows, then Windows automatically reloads unattended.
- When you reboot from Ubuntu, then Ubuntu automatically reloads unattended.
- If you don't want to automatically reboot to the last OS, then you have 10 seconds to override the default.

As far as Wayland goes, I wouldn't touch it with a ten foot pole because I have numerous X-11 only utilities and programs that are working perfectly with no Wayland substitution.

If you don't require customization, then Wayland will probably work fine.

If you have problems with Wayland then you should switch to X-11. If you have problems with Gnome then you can switch to Unity (if you like the Desktop Manager). Using software because it might be the future isn't justified when it's broken.

Comment: thank you but i was unable to  change the boot acoording to the first solution, its said command not found , however using files manager i was able to open the file but not using the terminal. so it didnt work for me